# Predis - how to use array with zadd function?

Tags: php, caching, redis, predis

I've just started using Predis for Redis migration and I'm having trouble getting the zadd function to work with an array.

This code works:

```
foreach ($userIndexArr as $row) {
  $usernames[] = 0;
  $usernames[] = $row['username']; 
  $result = $this->cache->zadd('@person', 0, $row['username']);
}
```

This doesn't:

```
foreach ($userIndexArr as $row) {
  $usernames[] = 0;
  $usernames[] = $row['username']; 
}
try {
    $result = $this->cache->zadd('@person', $usernames);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

And no error is thrown.  Any help is much appreciated!

-J

Answer (score 5):

I played around with this and if you're struggling with this the following example will surely help (following the [redis.io documents](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) example):

```
$predis->zadd( 'myset', [ "one" => 1, "uno" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3 ] )
```

this will result in the same sorted set as on redis' example:

```
ZADD myzset 1 "one"
ZADD myzset 1 "uno"
ZADD myzset 2 "two" 3 "three"
```

tricky part of that if you want to do this in one line in Redis you would put the scores first, like so:

```
ZADD myzset 1 "one" 1 "uno" 2 "two" 3 "three"
```

in Predis, this would work as well:

```
$predis->zadd( 'myset', 1, "one", 1, "uno", 2, "two", 3, "three" );
```

Answer (score 3):

When using predis you must send the member as key and the score as value

```
$predis->zadd('your:table', array('member' => 'score');
```

for examples in redis [docs](https://redis.io/commands/zadd#history) it would be:

```
$predis->zadd('myzset', array('uno' => 1, 'two' => 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, according to this source: https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.0/src/Command/ZSetAdd.php

```
foreach ($userIndexArr as $row) {
    $usernames[$row['username']] = 0; 
}
try {
    $result = $this->cache->zadd('@person', $usernames);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Untested, though. But I think it works, as long as you're using v1.0 =)

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Still using the zadd in for loop.  Is there a way to do this using execute raw?

Comment: Check you Predis version, also issue a `MONITOR` in redis-cli to check what is the current command your code is sending.

Comment: So, have you checked monitor command to see what's being output ? Also please tell me your Predis version.

Comment: Hi, very sorry for the late reply.  Had something a workaround so had to move on.

Tried your code as is and it worked like a charm.  Many thanks!